# Reconnect to wi-fi

Tags: android, connection, android-wifi, reconnect

I have android 4.4.2 version. When I do the code below on my device , then everything works fine , but when testing occurs on the device android 4.4.4 when you attempt `wifiManager.reconnect ();` off with an error.

```
 public static void reconnect1(){
    try {
    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
        if (i.SSID.equals(FirstSettings_two.first_ssid)) {
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
            wifiManager.reconnect();
            break;
        }
    } } catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();};
    }

public static void disconnect(){
    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
        if(i.SSID.equals( FirstSettings_two.first_ssid )) {
            WifiConfiguration conf =  new WifiConfiguration();
            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
            wifiManager.disconnect();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

*All code class [there](https://gist.github.com/diha-o/6038d4854bc0f5acf78f).*

Unfortunately I can not see the error code or logcat because the person being tested for 4.4.4 away from me.I do not understand why this is happening , I have the same working all good, maybe not the Problem in the phone and configure the router? I should point encryption type on wi-fi `WPA2-Personal`, and he did not know.

Comment: `Unfortunately I can not see the error `. Just place a Toast in the catch block to display e.getMessage().

Comment: Add `wifiManager.disconnect();` before `wifiManager.enableNetwork()`.